# React Native Send sms within the app

Tags: android, ios, react-native, sms

I want to send sms to multiple numbers without opening to default messaging app.
I try to use `react-native-sms-x` but its not maintained and my project just stuck at compiling.
Also I used `react-native-sms` but it open default Messaging App filled with one user number and message body and had to click send button of it too.

Comment: do you have a answer for this? I'm looking for the same function as well, thank you!

Answer (score 7):

```
import { Linking,Platform  } from "react-native";

    const url = (Platform.OS === 'android')
    ? 'sms:919999999999?body=your message'
    : 'sms:919999999999'
    Linking.canOpenURL(url).then(supported => {
      if (!supported) {
        console.log('Unsupported url: ' + url)
      } else {
        return Linking.openURL(url)
      }
    }).catch(err => console.error('An error occurred', err))
```

Comment: I think it will open default sms app filled with given sms number and message.

Answer (score 5):

After a lot of research and trials in the react app...
I have found [this](https://github.com/briankabiro/react-native-get-sms-android) library working fine and reached the goals to send a message without going into the default message environment.

```
var phoneNumbers = {
        "addressList": ["+911212121212", "+911212121212"]
      };
    var message = "This is automated test message"
    SmsAndroid.autoSend(
        phoneNumbers,
        message,
        (fail) => {
            console.log('Failed with this error: ' + fail);
        },
        (success) => {
            console.log('SMS sent successfully');
        },
    );
```

I hope it helps you. Do not forget to upvote

Comment: This is the best library I've ever worked, just to ask your experience is it helped to you ?

Answer (score 1):

From Now Just For Android I use [react-native-sms-android](https://github.com/rhaker/react-native-sms-android) 
Here is my Code for Sending sms to multiple users:

```
import Asms from "react-native-sms-android";
type Props = {};
export default class App extends Component<Props> {
  constructor(Props) {
        super(Props);
        this.state = { FileNumbers: ['687867867867','8575774433'], Message: 
          "gjjgjgj" };
         }

  sendingSms = (Receivers, Messagex) => {
           try {
                Receivers.map(
                async Numbers =>
                  await Asms.sms(Numbers, Messagex, "sendDirect", (err,message) 
                    => {
                    if (err) {
                      console.log(err);
                    } else {
                      console.log(message);
                    }
                  })
              );
            } catch (e) {
              alert("" + e);
            }
          };

      render() {
        return (
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <TextInput
              style={{
                height: 40,
                borderColor: "gray",
                borderWidth: 1,
                width: "90%"
              }}
              onChangeText={Message => this.setState({ Message })}
              value={this.state.Message}
            />
            <Button
              title="SEND"
              onPress={() =>
                this.sendingSms(this.state.FileNumbers, this.state.Message)
              }
            />

          </View>
        );
      }
    }
```